# Override default Fluent NHibernate Column Mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to find the syntax for changing the automap behavior of Fluent NHibernate.

How would I modify the code below to map the *UserId* property to a column named *UserIdentifier* (as an example)?

```
public class MyTypeMap : ClassMap<MyType>
{
    public MyTypeMap()
    {
            Table("MyTypes");
            Id(x => x.InstanceId).GeneratedBy.Guid().UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);
            Map(x=> x.UserId);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyTypeMap : ClassMap<MyType>
{
    public MyTypeMap()
    {
            Table("MyTypes");
            Id(x => x.InstanceId).GeneratedBy.Guid().UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);
            Map(x=> x.UserId).Column("UserIdentifier");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyTypeMap : ClassMap<MyType>
{
   public MyTypeMap()
   {
        Id (x => x.InstanceId).Column ("UserIdentifier").GeneratedBy.Guid().UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);
   }
}
```

Comment: why the downgrade ? This is perfectly ok.